# Como usar a função preventDefault em um evento click dentro em um iframe?

Tags: jquery, eventos, click

Eu manipulo o DOM do iframe da seguinte forma: (http://api.jquery.com/contents/)

```
$('iframe').contents().find('a').função();
```

Costumamos utilizar a função preventDefault assim:

```
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

**Dúvida:**

Como faço para utilizar a função `preventDefault()` em um evento click para todos as tags de link `$('a')` dentro do iframe? Basicamente preciso que nenhum link possa ser clicado dentro do iframe.

Já testei da seguinte forma, porém não funciona:

```
$('iframe').contents().find('a').click(function (e) { 
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Acho que podes marcar uma das respostas como certa :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolver o problema, caso a iFrame seja do mesmo domínio que a página mãe, é necessário adicionar o evento `.ready()` ao iframe, pois o mesmo deve ser carregado por completo antes de aplicar o evento `.click()`. Ficando da seguinte forma:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#id_do_iframe").ready(function () {
        $('#id_do_iframe').contents().find('a').click(function (e) { 
             e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Se a iFrame estiver num dominio diferente essa sua solução com jQuery não vai funcionar pois viola uma regra de segurança e os Browsers não permitem isso.

Uma solução que vejo é bloquear a iFrame com uma `div` na sua página, que fique por cima da iFrame, e assim "tapar" a interação com a iFrame.

Outra opção, ainda melhor (para browsers modernos) é a [solução do renan](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43869/129) com pointer events.

#### Exemplo:

(repare que dei uma border na div bloqueadora só para ser visivel)

```css
#bloqueador {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    border: 2px solid #ccf;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="http://www.cnn.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<div id="bloqueador"></div>
```

Comment: @GustavoPiucco vou apagar os comments aqui para limpar. Se fizer o mesmo seria ótimo e poupamos tempo dos moderadores

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução somente usando CSS seria usar a propriedade `pointer-events` no `<iframe>`. Só precisa ficar atento a [quais navegadores suportam](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events).

```css
iframe {
  pointer-events: none
}
```

```html
<iframe src="http://tympanus.net/codrops/" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)